# create different types of job in jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, groovy

How can I create different types of Jenkins projects like Maven, Multi configuration etc. and configures them using groovy script that can be run on Jenkins script console? or is there any Jenkins-cli command available in order to achieve this.

In case you know any other approach apart from this please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Jenkins Job DSL Plugin...write in Groovy ...

Answer (score 0):

First - You need the appropriate plugins for the different job types (like the [Maven plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Maven+Project+Plugin)).

If you'll read a bit about the CLI (JenkinsMaster:port/cli/) you can see that you have many actions you can do. One of them is to create a job:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://JenkinsMaster:Port/ create-job NAME
```

You will need to define a job configuration file (a simple xml file) to add using the CLI. 
I would suggest creating a Maven job for example, go to your $JENKINS_HOME/jobs folder and see how the xml file is written to better understand what it is you need to do.

And I would also suggest to try and read about Jenkins and how jobs are configured and work. I will add links to great tutorials if needed - comment if you intend to learn and interested.

Comment: Thanks Dvir669...That's a great help.....I am very much interested to learn this.. Let me provide you some more info on what I need to do....I need to write a script that will create different types of jobs in Jenkins which is hosted on some other machine....With Script console one can write a groovy script and using Curl  command we can execute this groovy script in script console.....I know how to create a freestyle job using a groovy script but not sure how we can create different kinds of jobs like Maven, Multi configuration etc.